# How to invoke a pre-installed contract in another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, contract

First I pre-install a contract A(address(A)). Then I install a contract B (address(B)) to invoke A by using call interface. Lastly I invoke the contract by using his address(x). I meant to use the address(x) to invoke A, but actually the address(B) invoke A. So how can I use address(x) to invoke A?"

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract TransferERC20 {

    event TransferEvent (
        bool _flag,
        string _invoiceId,
        address _erc20ContractHash,
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    function transfer(string _invoiceId, address _erc20ContractHash,address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool) {
        bytes4 methodTransfer = bytes4(keccak256("transfer(address,uint256)"));
        if(_erc20ContractHash.call(methodTransfer, _to, _amount)) {
            emit TransferEvent(true, _invoiceId, _erc20ContractHash, _from, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        }
        emit TransferEvent(false, _invoiceId, _erc20ContractHash, _from, _to, _amount);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code intends to call ERC20 contract which is pre-installed on ethereum testnet. However I invoke failed because the address is changed to the the TransferERC20 address. How can I realize the transfer function by using the TransferERC20 callor's address. THKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token holder first needs to set an allowance using `approve` on the ERC20 token for the TransferERC20 contract and only then can they call `transfer` on the TransferERC20 contract which should call `transferFrom` on the ERC20 token.
This requires two transactions, one for `approve` and one for `transferFrom`.

If you are creating ERC20 tokens you may want to look at the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation to see if this meets your needs.
See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20

Alternatively you could look at creating ERC777 tokens (no need to do `approve` and `transferFrom` in two separate transactions).  See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC777

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: TKS, I have solved the problem by following your suggestion. ^>^

Comment: Great, glad I could help.  You can mark my response as the answer.